# Is there any way to assert valid sha1 ,valid epoch timestamp and positive integer in python without using any thrid party library?

Tags: python, validation, assert

Is there any direct way to assert valid sha1 ,valid epoch timestamp and valid positive integer in python.I am bound to use native python and no third party libs.

Comment: Please explain your question further. What do you mean by "assert valid"? What is a "valid utc timestamp"?

Comment: A built-in (for python >=2.5) hashlib module provides sha1 calculation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html?highlight=sha1); epoch timestamp is in utc, isn't it? epoch ts is available in a built-in time module: time.time(). assert is a built-in expression. I don't see a need for any third-party library.

Comment: You can do all those things with python, see the hashlib and datetime modules. You need to explain more about the validation part.